# How to join document in SOLR

Tags: csv, solr

I have 4 CSV files which I am indexing in the same core.

- PRESCRIBER.csv

  - Fields: PRESCRIBER_ID, PRESCRIBER_TYPE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MIDDLE_INITIAL, DEA_NUMBER, DEA_SUFFIX, UPIN_NUMBER, SPIN_NUMBER, ACTIVE_FLAG, RESPONSIBLE_PRESCRIBER_ID, FACILITY_ID, LOCK_COL
- PRESCRIBER_ADDRESS.csv

  - Fields: PRESCRIBER_ID, ADDRESS_ID, LOCATION_TYPE, PRIMARY_FLAG, LOCK_COL, PRESCRIBER_LOCATION_CODE
- PRESCRIBER_TELEPHONE.csv

  - Fields: PRESCRIBER_ID, TELEPHONE_ID, PRIMARY_FLAG, LOCK_COL
- TELEPHONE.csv

  - Fields: TELEPHONE_ID, TELEPHONE_TYPE, AREA_CODE, TELEPHONE_NUMBER, EXTENSION,    LOCK_COL

I want to imitate the below SQL query in SOLR:

```
    SELECT * FROM PRESCRIBER INNER JOIN PRESCRIBER_TELEPHONE ON
    PRESCRIBER.PRESCRIBER_ID = PRESCRIBER_TELEPHONE.PRESCRIBER_ID
    INNER JOIN TELEPHONE ON
    PRESCRIBER_TELEPHONE.TELEPHONE_ID = TELEPHONE.TELEPHONE_ID
    WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE '%A%' AND FIRST_NAME LIKE '%B%'
    AND ISNULL(PRESCRIBER_TELEPHONE.PRIMARY_FLAG,'') = 'Y'
```

I have written the below SOLR query:

```
    http://160.110.9.39:8983/solr/prscrbrDtls/select?q=*:*&fq=FIRST_NAME:*B*&fq=LAST_NAME:*A*&fq:{!join+from=PRESCRIBER_ID+to=PRESCRIBER_ID}TELEPHONE_ID{!join+from=TELEPHONE_ID+to=TELEPHONE_ID}PRIMARY_FLAG:Y&rows=5000
```

**Issue:**

I am only seeing the fields from PRESCRIBER.csv.

```
    {"PRESCRIBER_ID":[XX],
    "PRESCRIBER_TYPE":["MD"],
    "FIRST_NAME":["ELIZABETH"],
    "LAST_NAME":["CHAVEZ"],
    "MIDDLE_INITIAL":["O"],
    "DEA_NUMBER":["XX"],
    "ACTIVE_FLAG":["X"],
    "LOCK_COL":[3],
    "id":"d35e4c68-9cb2-477a-ad03-7ab25bc5490d",
    "_version_":1608393436695625743}
```

I want to see all the fields together from PRESCRIBER, PRESCRIBER_TELEPHONE and TELEPHONE in the response JSON.

1. Any pointers on how to do that?
2. Am I writing the query correct?

Additional Question:
How can I remove _str fields from SOLR response?

Answer (score 1):

You're writing your query correct, but [joins in Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser) does not allow you to fetch anything else than what's in the primary collection you're querying. It's one of the fundamental limitations of joins in Solr.

> This is different from the concept of a join in a relational database because no information is being truly joined. An appropriate SQL analogy would be an "inner query".

If you need to fetch data on multiple sides of a query, you can use a [Streaming Expression](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/streaming-expressions.html), with either [innerJoin](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/stream-decorators.html#stream-decorators), [hashJoin](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/stream-decorators.html#hashjoin), [leftOuterJoin](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/stream-decorators.html#leftouterjoin) or one of the other join decorators. Streaming Expressions requires a fairly recent version of Solr.

Comment: Thanks, I am definitely going to try this out. For now as a quickfix, I am creating nested JSON from multiple CSV files.